# Civicrm Error Message

Tags: contacts, error, issues

I am facing the following error when click to view a contact. Could someone please assist me?
[image]

Here is more details of the error:
Oct 17 16:04:46  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}

Oct 17 16:04:55  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "Invalid field 'Contribution_Contact_contact_id_01_Contact_EntityTag_Tag_01_Tag_EntityTag_Contact_01.tag_id'"
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#28591
-errorData: array:1 [
"error_code" => 0
]
#cause: null
-_trace: null
#message: "Invalid field 'Contribution_Contact_contact_id_01_Contact_EntityTag_Tag_01_Tag_EntityTag_Contact_01.tag_id'"
#code: 0
#file: "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php"
#line: 372
trace: {
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:372 {
Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->getField($expr, $strict = false)
› if ($strict && $field === NULL) {
›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Invalid field '$fieldName'");
› }
}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4Query.php:166 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4Query.php:297 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4Query.php:213 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:563 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:464 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:92 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/Meta.php:34 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/AfformSearchMetadataInjector.php:74 { …}
Civi\Search\AfformSearchMetadataInjector::Civi\Search{closure}() {}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/ChangeSet.php:59 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/ChangeSet.php:19 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php:295 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Modules.php:160 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Modules.php:82 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:251 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:263 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:168 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:2728 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php:226 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php:198 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php:136 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/AngularLoader.php:169 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/CollectionTrait.php:394 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:142 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:157 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1116 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:334 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-header.php:163 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:1686 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:202 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php:272 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php:86 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:334 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
/var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
}
}
]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the circumstances? Version? Happens on every contact? Installation clean and working before?  Caches cleared? Strange extensions installed and disabled or removed? Tags widely used, even on contributions?